# launching issue in Tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, android-tabs

In my app I have two tabs, tab1 and tab2. By default tab1 opens.If I click on tab2 and then press home button. and then restart device. If I launch app again tab2 is opening. 
How its working?

Comment: Because your application was still running, and your activity was not destroyed

Comment: I have restared my device. so all app should kill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a static boolean, and when you're application calls `onDestroy()` you set the boolean to false. In `onResume()` you will have to check if the boolean is true or false, when it is false you navigate to the first page.

Also see [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)